# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I've ran into the common error of **Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)**. I have looked into other questions on SO, but none of these have answered my question.

The error appears on the 4th line of the following code:

```
if content[indexPath.row].urgent == true {
        cell.urgentLabel.text = "URGENT"
} else {
        cell.urgentLabel.text = ""
}
```

Other questions on SO say that I should have the `""` in the 4th line, but how would I fix this, that it still displays no text.

This code corresponds with the following array:

```
var content:[Agenda] = [
    Agenda(subject: "Read this article", deadline: "1-2 days", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Respond to this email", deadline: "ASAP", urgent: true),
    Agenda(subject: "Add this to diary", deadline: "When at home", urgent: true),
    Agenda(subject: "Listen to this song", deadline: "When finished working", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Check out this holiday destination", deadline: "At the weekend", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Download this podcast", deadline: "1-4 days", urgent: false),
    Agenda(subject: "Update notes", deadline: "When at home", urgent: true)
]
```

Comment: Verify that urgentLabel is properly connected.

Comment: @EricD.Oops! That was the problem. Place that as the answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't see any forced-unwrapped optionals in this code, this issue does not come from this common problem.

Still, it's a forced unwrapped nil issue, so... it could come from an *implicitly unwrapped optional*, for example an IBOutlet.

If the connection between InterfaceBuilder and the IBOutlet is lost, the object will be nil and the app will crash when trying to access the object properties.

The solution is to re-create the link to the IBOutlet/object, in your case `urgentLabel`, in InterfaceBuilder.